# As a beginner, what whould the approach to go for testing IOT/AI/ML/Deep Learning applications?

Tags: application-software-testing, artificial-intelligence

Seeking some primary approach to go for testing of cutting edge technology application.

Comment: This is far too broad to answer appropriately. Imagine for a moment a couple really good answers were provided, how would you be able to tell which was deserving of the green check? It also lacks background in the real world problem, or even theoretical problem, you're facing. Please revise. Thanks!